# Program Logic to show two customized dialogs with in one onCreateDialog()?

Tags: java, android

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    static final int DIALOG_ID_X = 0;
    static final int DIALOG_ID_Y = 1;

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            showDialog(DIALOG_ID_X);

        }
    });
   button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            showDialog(DIALOG_ID_Y);

        }
    });
```

}

Above is my main activity class and trying to open two customize dialogs upon clicking the two buttons (b1,b2). So my problem is b1 is working fine(Dialog opens correctly) but b2 is not working. Any idea how to let the b2 work?

Any help will be appreciated.

mrana...

Comment: what does not working mean? also post the whole code and also logs if any

Comment: means there is some issue with switch which is not recognizing button b2..

Comment: @nandeesh i have added the code and just guessing issue lies where i have initialized the dialog variable=null.In logcat its showing FATAL exception witin the main class which i have put above.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine at first glance, so there might be a small typo or an issue elsewhere in the code.

Try Adding logging statements right below your`case` statements, or use debug breakpoints.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    Dialog dialog = null;

    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ID_X:
           Log.i("dialog","showing dialog X");
           //Code for showing customize layout dialog 1
        case DIALOG_ID_Y:
           Log.i("dialog","showing dialog Y");
```

Then, run it, and hit both buttons.  If you don't see `showing dialog` in the logs, that means the problem is elsewhere.  If you do, that implies the error is in `case DIALOG_ID_Y`

Either way,  adding these two logging statements will help you (and us) find your problem.